# Создание таблицы с именем, заданным через переменную, в sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужно чтобы после ввода значение создавалась в бд таблица с таким названием , но я не знаю как конкретно написать потому что в данном случае происходит ошибка.

```
def createbd(event):
    o=o1.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE ? (id int auto_increment primary key,vopros char(150),otv1 varchar(50),otv2 varchar(50),otv3 varchar(50),pravotv varchar(50))',o)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, это не форум экстрасенсов и понять какая у вас ошибка задача хоть не сложная, но лучше с такими вопросами трассу с стеком сопровождайте :) Скорее всего у вас нет папки `bd`, в которую и пытаетесь базу сохранить. Либо ошибка при выполнении sql запроса. Либо ошибка при интерпретации кода (у ваш представленный код не выполнится из-за отсутствия отступа). Либо ошибка в o1.get().

Comment: ошибка near "?": syntax error
на счет отступов сайт исправил сам

Comment: связанный вопрос [Create Table using a variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34392011/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подстановочные символы нельзя использовать в позиции имени таблицы. Вам придётся использовать конкатенацю строк:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE ' + o + ' (id int auto_increment primary key,vopros char(150),otv1 varchar(50),otv2 varchar(50),otv3 varchar(50),pravotv varchar(50))')
```

И лучше озаботится тем, чтобы в `o` не оказалось символов, которые могут привести к [sql injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0):

```
import re

r = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')

def createbd(event):
    o = o1.get()
    if o:
        o = r.sub('', o)
    ...
```

Comment: B почему люди так не любят `.format()`?)

Comment: если в имени таблицы есть неразрешённые символы, то лучше исключение выбросить (баг, неверный ввод), а не пытаться какое-то другое имя получить.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin: `.format()` делает менее очевидными какие части строки переменные. Учитывая, что следует избегать создания sql запросов прямым форматированием строки (если этого можно избежать), то более явная форма (когда нельзя избежать), которая подчёркивает значения какой переменной особого внимания заслуживают, более предпочтительна.